# Info command doesn't exist

Tags: command-line, bash, info

I was looking at the output of `man tar`, which says that if I want more information, I should use `info tar`.  I do want more information; however, when I try this, bash returns the error

```
bash: info: command not found
```

Is there a package I need to download in order to use the `info` command?  If not, what must I do to remedy the situation?

Comment: You haven't given your release of Ubuntu.  `info tar` works perfectly for me using a desktop (Lubuntu 19.10), however some minimal installs reduce size by reducing information available, so this may be your issue - but I'm guessing as you've not given a starting point (ie. release/flavor of OS, desktop/server/... etc)

Comment: The command `info` on my system is provided by `info` package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/info), possibly it's been removed on your system as it's included ('main') on most if not all Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I'm using crouton to chroot Ubuntu.  Also, I tried `apt install info`, and while it did allow `info tar` to work, all that it did was spit out it's manpage.

Comment: That means the `info` data pages aren't there on your system either.  `info` falls back to using `man` pages where it doesn't have any further datafiles for your request .. adding everything takes space; so it's optional (to avoid complaints of 'bloat')

Comment: ... specifically, the info pages for tar are in a separate package `tar-doc` and `apt show tar-doc` appears to indicate that it is omitted by default for licensing reasons